# NSString drawAtPoint with

Tags: ios, uiimage

I want to make some UIImage with label, which will show, if photo isn't loaded.
Generation of this image in application is more useful, because it very easy to localize text.
I have code:

```
NSString *text = @"Photo not loaded yet. Please wait.";
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:35];
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(400, 400);

CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(imageSize.width * 0.8f, imageSize.height * 0.8f);
CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0);

CGPoint pointToDraw = CGPointMake((imageSize.width - textSize.width) / 2, (imageSize.height - textSize.height) / 2);

[text drawAtPoint:pointToDraw forWidth:textSize.width withFont:font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
```

But it draw only first line, like in screenshot.

[image: Simulator screenshot]

Where I was wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Logging out textSize will at least tell you whether the problem is with the size returned from `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` or the actual drawing.

Comment: Why not just add a label and remove it when the image is available? Or an activity indicator?

Comment: Far easier to use a UILabel to display your message.  Hide the UIImageView (set its hidden property to YES) and show the UILabel (set hidden to NO).

Comment: It is more easy for me, to make this UIImage, because image displayed in a lot of places: I need to put to all places labels or activity indicators, or just make a simple UIImage. Anyway, I think, it should work.

Comment: You're right, it should work (and it does, if you use the right method -- see my answer). And whether it's the best solution or not, it's completely reasonable to want to draw a string; that's exactly why NSString provides methods for drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawAtPoint%3aforWidth%3awithFont%3afontSize%3alineBreakMode%3abaselineAdjustment%3a) for `-drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:`:

> Draws the string in a single line at the specified point in the current graphics context using the specified font and attributes.

Ergo, use a different method. `-drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:` looks like a solid candidate.