# how to fix the depreciated warnings related to sizeWithFont and drawAtPoint?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am trying to incorporate a sample code that was written for pre iOS 7 in my demo project. i am getting some depreciated methods related to `drawAtPoint` and `sizeWithFont`. i have read through a bunch of SO entries with the same problem but they are all related to labels and tableview cell and etc. i am trying to draw a pdf into my view and somehow i can't come up with the right set of code with the new methods. i am truly appreciative of any help guys. here is the section of the class I'm using:

```
UIFont* studentNameFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
UIFont* classFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

CGFloat currentPageY = 0;

for (NSDictionary* student in students)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, kDefaultPageWidth, kDefaultPageHeight), nil);
    currentPageY = kMargin;

    NSString* name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                      [student objectForKey:@"FirstName"],
                      [student objectForKey:@"LastName"]];

    // depreciated method
    CGSize size = [name sizeWithFont:studentNameFont forWidth:maxWidth lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    //depreciated method
    [name drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(kMargin, currentPageY) forWidth:maxWidth withFont:studentNameFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    currentPageY += size.height;

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, kMargin, currentPageY);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, kDefaultPageWidth - kMargin, currentPageY);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    NSArray* classes = [student objectForKey:@"Classes"];
    for(NSDictionary* class in classes)
    {
        NSString* className = [class objectForKey:@"Name"];
        NSString* grade = [class objectForKey:@"Grade"];

    //depreciated method
        size = [className sizeWithFont:classFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(classNameMaxWidth, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        // if the current text would render beyond the bounds of the page,
        // start a new page and render it there instead
        if (size.height + currentPageY > maxHeight) {
            // create a new page and reset the current page's Y value
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, kDefaultPageWidth, kDefaultPageHeight), nil);
            currentPageY = kMargin;
        }
        //depreciated method
        [className drawInRect:CGRectMake(kMargin, currentPageY, classNameMaxWidth, maxHeight) withFont:classFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

        //depreciated method
        [grade drawInRect:CGRectMake(kMargin + classNameMaxWidth + kColumnMargin, currentPageY, gradeMaxWidth, maxHeight) withFont:classFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

        currentPageY += size.height;

    }
```

Comment: Are developing for iOS 7 only ?

Comment: Then you have the answer bellow by C_X, and for drawAtPoint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535974/nsstring-drawatpoint-with

Comment: You fix the deprecation issues by reading the documentation for the deprecated method and using the new method referenced in those docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method

```
[className sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:classFont}];
```

Comment: accepted your answer pal. if you get a chance can you help out with the other warnings?